# Android use multiple different row on RecyclerView for DataBinding feature

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

Basically i can use multiple row on recyclerview adaper without any problem such as this code:

```
@Override
public ShowBookItemsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    int layout = -1;
    switch (viewType) {
        case 1:
            layout = R.layout.item_heading_one;
            break;
        case 2:
            layout = R.layout.item_heading_two;
            break;
    }

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout, parent, false);
    ShowBookItemsViewHolder holder = new ShowBookItemsViewHolder(v);
    return holder;
}
```

now i'm trying to use this feature when i'm using DataBinding, but i get an error and i can't do that

this is my wrong code:

```
@Override
public RobotViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    int layout = -1;
    if (inflater == null) {
        switch (viewType) {
            case 0:
                layout = R.layout.robot_item_action;
                break;
            case 1:
                layout = R.layout.robot_user_action;
                break;
        }
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    }
    RobotDataBinding dataBinding = RobotDataBinding.inflate(layout, parent, false);
    return new RobotViewHolder(dataBinding);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to bind the adapter's views before its view holder is instantiated. View binding should be performed in [onBindViewHolder()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)).

Create a base view holder class that extends `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` and has an abstract bind(Object obj) method that `ShowBookItemsViewHolder` and `RobotViewHolder` implement. Credit to George Mount for this approach.

```
public abstract class BaseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ...

    // delegate binding to child class
    protected abstract void bind(Object obj);
}
```

Then in `onBindViewHolder()`:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(adapterData.get(position)
}
```

This will pass your adapterData object to the child view holder for binding:

```
public class ShowBookItemsViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder {

    ...

    public void bind(Object obj) {
        // Bind here...
    }
}
```

Override `getItemViewType()` to supply `onCreateViewHolder()` with different view types. For example:

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // Change layout every other position
    return position % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Use the view type to construct the view holders:

```
public BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == 0) {
        return new ShowBookItemsViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.your_layout, parent, false) 
    else {
        return new RobotViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.your_layout, parent, false) 
    }
}
```

Make sure `onCreateViewHolder()` returns the base view holder and the adapter class extends `RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.YourBaseViewHolder>`.

Comment: for this adapter which i have two row, how can i manage both of them on single recyclerview view holder? this is very difficult for me for understand

Comment: @Develope500 do you have free time to fix this problem on my project?

Comment: Yeah sure, I will try to help. In your question you inflate two layouts in onCreateViewHolder - R.layout.robot_item_action & R.layout.robot_user_action. I presume the two layouts are different? i.e. they have different views in the XML file. If this is the case, it would be better to have a view holder for each one to hold the respective views.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138211/discussion-between-tux-world-and-user123).

Comment: I would use a base class extending `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` with a `public abstract void bind(Object ob);` and have each of `ShowBookItemsViewHolder` and `RobotViewHolder` implement that method. Then your `onBindViewHolder` doesn't need the switch. It can just call `holder.bind(adapterData.get(position));`

Comment: Thanks. That is a more elegant approach. I have updated the solution.